# How to check if input form value is changed before injecting it in mysql (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a simple form in codeigniter to let users update their info. I am trying to check if a user's **first name** is updated when the user saves their info.

The user might update last name and date of birth but not first name, when saving the form, which I need to know.

So how do I check if the input form value is updated or not, before inserting it into mysql table.

This is what my model page looks like, but its not working.

**CODE**

```
if ('first_name' != $first_name)
    {
        $data['first_name_edited']      = 1;
        $data['update_fname_date']  = 'date('Y-m-d')';
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: **select data from the respective user and compare with new inputs.**

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply not provide a form element to edit the first name?

Answer (score 0):

compare the firstname value from database & the one which you get from form submission.

```
if ($db_first_name != $new_first_name)
{
    $data['first_name_edited']      = 1;
    $data['update_fname_date']  = 'date('Y-m-d')';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @softech, I am trying to do that, but I dont know how to get the value that is inputted in the form field. 

$first_name =! 'first name' is not working

Comment: [Simple Login Form With CodeIgniter](https://jrtashjian.com/2009/02/simple-login-form-with-codeigniter-2/) This link can help you. Or you can get many more tutorials on Internet.